# Make an array of the names in <h1></h1>, and the ages in <h2></h2>

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make an array of the names in `<h1></h1>`, and the ages in `<h2></h2>`

Can I use map() method? And how do it work?
Beside, Any solve?

```
function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr) {

}

readyToPutInTheDOM([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
]) 
// ["<h1>Angelina Jolie</h1><h2>80</h2>", 
// "<h1>Eric Jones</h1><h2>2</h2>", 
// "<h1>Paris Hilton</h1><h2>5</h2>", 
// "<h1>Kayne West</h1><h2>16</h2>", 
// "<h1>Bob Ziroll</h1><h2>100</h2>"]
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: @MarkMeyer No, I haven't. I want to some code to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the map method. Map works by looping over each entry in your array, then depending on what you `return` at each iteration determines what that particular array entry is converted to (ie mapped to).  So, you can simply return each array entries object properties wrapped in `<h1></h1>` and `<h2></h2>` tags like so:

```js
function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(obj) {
    return "<h1>" +obj.name +"</h1>" + "<h2>" + obj.age +"</h2>";
  });
}

var result = readyToPutInTheDOM([{name:"Angelina Jolie",age:80},{name:"Eric Jones",age:2},{name:"Paris Hilton",age:5},{name:"Kayne West",age:16},{name:"Bob Ziroll",age:100}]);
console.log(result);
```

Or, you could use ES6 arrow functions, destructuring and template literals:

```js
const readyToPutInTheDOM = arr => 
  arr.map(({name, age}) => `<h1>${name}</h1><h2>${age}</h2>`);

const result = readyToPutInTheDOM([{name:"Angelina Jolie",age:80},{name:"Eric Jones",age:2},{name:"Paris Hilton",age:5},{name:"Kayne West",age:16},{name:"Bob Ziroll",age:100}]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` or `map` like this

```
function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr) {
  arr.map(c=> {
     document.write("<h1>" + c.name + "</h1>");
     document.write("<h2>" + c.age+ "</h2>");
  });

  arr.forEach(c=> {
     document.write("<h1>" + c.name + "</h1>");
     document.write("<h2>" + c.age+ "</h2>");
  });
}
```

```js
function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr) {
  arr.map(c=> {
     document.write("<h1>" + c.name + "</h1>");
     document.write("<h2>" + c.age+ "</h2>");
  });
  
  arr.forEach(c=> {
     document.write("<h1>" + c.name + "</h1>");
     document.write("<h2>" + c.age+ "</h2>");
  });
}

readyToPutInTheDOM([
  {
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop inside your JSON data using `each` and bind on DOM like below.

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Angelina Jolie",
    age: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Eric Jones",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Paris Hilton",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Kayne West",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Ziroll",
    age: 100
  }
];
var nHTML = '';
$(data).each(function(i, val) {
  nHTML += '<h1>' + val['name'] + '</h1>';
  nHTML += '<h2>' + val['age'] + '</h2>';
});
$('#display').html(nHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='display'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear so I don't sure that its what u want

```
function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr) {
  let x = document.createElement('div');
  arr.map((v,i)=>{
    x.innerHTML += `<h1> ${v.name}</h1> <h2>${v.age}</h2>`;
  });
   document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this task is easily completed this way.

```
 function readyToPutInTheDOM(arr: { name: string; age: number }[]) {
  return arr.map(
    (arr) => "<h1>" + arr.name + "</h1>" + "<h2>" + arr.age + "</h2>"
  );
```